# How to setup a staging server using GIT?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm usint BitBucket and SourceTree, I did install a new repo and I'm able now to push and pull changes between the remote(bitBucket) and local files, however I can't figure out how to connect to another remote server and upload files to it from the repo?

What I mean is how can I make a staging.domain.com, so that I can push the changes to it?

Answer (score 0):

In SourceTree, menu Repository -> Add Remote

Comment: I did add the remote, now in the html/ directory there are some GIt files, but where are the source files?

Comment: "Some Git files"? What is it? Just pull/push changes from/to the another remote (both dialogs have dropdown box to choose a remote).

Comment: those are the files: branches, hooks, info, objects, .... etc
What I need to know is the location of my source files? my index.html and so

Comment: How have you added the remote? branches/hooks/info/etc are git repo files. You should have been adding new remote, not cloning another repo.